# qt creator 5.10 failed to retrieve msvc environment error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-c++, qt-creator

i just installed qt creator 5.10 and i opened a simple widget application  this is the error that i get even without running the application

```
:-1: error: Failed to retrieve MSVC Environment from "D:\pograml files\visual studio2\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat":
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

i haven't found any solutions for this, if anyone could help me i would be very thankful

Comment: Read this post https://forum.qt.io/post/392085 It is actual, although is for Qt 5.9.

Comment: `"D:\pograml files\..."` - Typo? I would check whether this `vcvarsall.bat` can be found at the noted location. Probably the error is - it cannot. `vcvarsall.bat` is a batch file which sets some env. variables to support using MSVC on command line. (Qt creator probably uses it for simple location of MS build tools.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to the answer of @John Wesley, I too had to alter my system's PATH enviroment variable to fix the "failed to retrieve msvc environment" error. However, my problem was slightly different.

In short, **remove any unused directories from your PATH**.

To explain, my PATH contained the following entries in the following order:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
[lots more enties followed...]
```

Hence my case was different to John's because it already had the required entries of:

```
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
```

The fix for my system was to delete the first two entries (which I do not need because I manually set my Java paths). After I did that, I reopened Qt Creator and it worked!

It has been working for the past week without problem, however, sometimes the message "failed to retrieve msvc environment" still pops up for a moment, but then disappears again.

Comment: So whats the relation of the PATH entries to the problem? which entries in my case could be causing such issue?!

Comment: @MohammadKanan I don't know for certain without knowing what is on your PATH. I can confirm that the above fix is still working weeks later. I don't know exactly why, but simplifying your PATH is a good first step to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 3):

When Qt starts, I used to get a list of 10 errors related to MSVC kit because each detected MSVC platform compiler has an *Initialization* script for setting environment.  like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64
```

I traced the failure by running all `Initialization` one by one on same command line (cmd) window; In the beginning I used to run only `Initialization` for `x86_amd64` which runs without errors thus I didn't notice anything wrong. But on same window running `Initialization` for next compiler " `...\vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64`" the error appeared which in my case was something like:

> " ..program Files\MySQL\Utilities xxx was not expected at this time"

I just checked and found that path does not exist at all in my storage, so I removed it from `PATH` system env settings, and surprised things went normal after that!

Answer (score 1):

I met this error building qt project in Qt Creator. then solved by adding some paths to my system path, which not included them before.

- C:\Windows\System32
- C:\Windows
- C:\Windows\System32\Wbem

Then reopen Qt Creator.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as you. I use Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition with Qt 5.6.0. Windows 10.

In the beginning, I used "Visual Studio Installer" to repair. However it does not work.

Then I append "C:\Windows\System32" to "PATH" variable to Environment variables" since chcp is a exe in System3 and somehow I cannot find "C:\Windows\System32" in "PATH".

After that, I delete the Visual Studio (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio) directly from File Explorer. ( I shift+deleted it )

Then re-install the "Visual Studio 2017" again.

It works!

I do not know which step is important. I think to add System32 to PATH variable and re-install VS2017 may the solution

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I found the problem in my System Path variable. If the Path contains double quote anywhere, Qt emits this error.

Answer (score -2):

I have meet the "error: Failed to retrieve MSVC Environment" for no reason. I deleated the debug file of my project and it does work.

Comment: And I also deleated the xxxxx.pro.user file.

Comment: Could you please give us a bit more information and context about your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask